# Multilingual content and SEO - best practices?

Tags: seo, multilingual, language, localization

Does having multilingual content help SEO in a given language?

I was thinking of paying to have my blog translated into other languages - my website and app are only available in English right now, but I'll be adding localization in many languages over 2023 and I was thinking of translating my blog articles into those languages.

Is this generally a good idea? I would basically have the same article, but instead of at:

https://example.com/blog/story-goes-here

It would be

https://example.com/blog/en/story-goes-here

https://example.com/blog/es/story-goes-here

etc

How should I determine what language to direct users to? Just their browser settings?

Answer (score 2):

> Does having multilingual content help SEO in a given language?

Does translating English articles into Spanish and French improve the rankings of the English content? No.

Over time, there could be positive spillover effects if you build a brand and gain backlinks in the other languages.

Short-term, you only add complexity and need to get Google to crawl and index x-times as much content as before.

> Is this generally a good idea?

It depends.

Downside:

- You will spend x% of time translating content which will either slow down content production or make content production more expensive.
- You will need to set your website up for handling multiple languages, which adds complexity to templates, UX design, UI design, and internal linking logic.
- You might have to set-up and maintain hreflang to avoid the wrong language-version ranking in some countries.
- For maximum impact, you must promote your website/brand/content in every language and build links in every language.

Upside:

- If your content is unique and there is already demand for it in other languages, this can be a low-hanging fruit.
- In some smaller languages (like Finnish) there is less demand. But also less competition. You might have it much easier to rank well.

> How should I determine what language to direct users to?

If you mean redirecting users, don't! Language/country redirects are one of the worst UX crimes a website can commit. Make it easy to switch the language version and potentially even suggest the most fitting one. But never redirect users - unless they have previously indicated a preference to always see your website in a certain language. Forced language/country redirects cause a lot of frustration!

Answer (score 1):

> Does having multilingual content help SEO in a given language?

Only if your translated content is adapted for native speakers of that language. E..g., Spanish-speaking users may have intents related to the entities of your content that are very different from those of English-speaking users. The same may be true within the domain of one language, e.g., Spanish-speaking users in Spain, users in Argentina, and users in Los Angeles or South Florida may have very different search intents related to your content. Your goal when creating multilingual content is to create content that is interesting to native speakers of the language and fits their mentality and their search intent.

> How should I determine what language to direct users to? Just their
> browser settings?

Check out what **[Google says about it](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/managing-multi-regional-sites#geotargeting)**:

> Don't use IP analysis to adapt your content. IP location analysis is
> difficult and generally not reliable. Furthermore, Google may not be
> able to crawl variations of your site properly. Most, but not all,
> Google crawls originate from the US, and we don't attempt to vary the
> location to detect site variations. Use one of the explicit methods
> shown here (hreflang, alternate URLs, and explicit links).